# Flutter PageController AnimateToPage breaks the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have been using page view with a page controller to move between pages in my flutter app, I have five screens. When I go from one page to another which is just adjacent to each other, then it's all fine. But when I go from let's say page with index 0 to 2, then the app hangs and nothing works, and there's no log or error shown, even with try and catch.

On the other hand if I use *pageController.jumpToPage()* then everything works perfectly.

This problem only showed up when I upgraded flutter to the latest version and all the dependencies.

This is the code that I've been using:

```
_pageController.animateToPage(index,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.easeIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter version 3.3.9
And IOS is fine.
But Android not work.

```
closeModalBottom(value, courseBrain) {
if (value == "wrong") { //if run this code not working page animate
  // Create Wrong Question Page
  final _wrongQuestion = getQuestionPage(courseBrain.history!);
  pages.add(_wrongQuestion);
}

_pageViewIndex = _pageViewIndex + 1;

// Animate Next Page
controller.animateToPage(
  _pageViewIndex,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  curve: Curves.ease,
);
```

}

Edit: I do Flutter downgrade 3.3.2 but not working again.

Answer (score 0):

I did not work index==0 in animateToPage
So, instead of index == 0, try starting with index==1

```
class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  Welcome({super.key});

  final PageController _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView(
            controller: _controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, //横にスライド
            children: [
              //first page
              appOnboardingPage(
                _controller,
                imagePath: 'assets/images/reading.png',
                title: 'First See Learning',
                subtitle:
                    'Forget about the paper, now learning all in one place',
                index: 1,//Doesn't work from 0
              ),
              //second page
              appOnboardingPage(
                _controller,
                imagePath: 'assets/images/man.png',
                title: 'Connect With Everyone',
                subtitle:
                    'Always keep in touch with your tutor and friends. Let`s get connected',
                index: 2,
              ),
              appOnboardingPage(
                _controller,
                imagePath: 'assets/images/boy.png',
                title: 'Always Fascinated Learning',
                subtitle:
                    'Anywhere, anytime. the is at your discretion. So study wherever you can',
                index: 3,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _nextButton(int index, PageController controller) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print("my index is $index");
      if (index < 3) {
        print(index);
        controller.animateToPage(index,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
      }
    },
    child: Container(
      width: 325,
      height: 50,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 25, right: 25),
      decoration: appBoxShadow(),
      child: Center(
        child: text16Normal(
          text: "next",
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).